# TYPO3: populate values in dropdown based on values in another dropdown

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

In my database I have a table named Category. Examples of a Category could be 'Mathematics' or 'Chemistry'.

My database also contains a second table named SubCategory which contains child elements associated with values in the Category table. Examples of values contained in SubCategory could be 'Fractions' or 'Logarithms' (associated with 'Mathematics' from Category) or 'Organic Chemistry', 'Analytical Chemistry' (associated with 'Chemistry' from Category).

I have a page created in Fluid, where I want a dropdown containing elements from my Category table. The page should contain a second dropdown, which will be populated by values based on the choice made in the first dropdown. So if the user chooses 'Mathematics' in the first dropdown, the second dropdown will contain 'Fractions', 'Logarithms' etc.. If the user chooses another option, then the values in the second dropdown will change accordingly.

This can be done in JavaScript/jQuery, but I was wondering if there was a solution available using Fluid, TypoScript or any other TYPO3 related technology.

Comment: Hello Eos,

there is a lot of way to handle this. To give you the good answer I would like to know what is supposed to happen when you've selected the final second select box choice ?

cheers,
Rakel

Comment: Hello Rakel. This should be part of a proces, where you are trying to create a new object. Let's say it's a question for a test. There are certain parameters, that need to be set, like 'Category' and 'Sub-category'. When everything is set, you press a Create button, and voila.

Comment: ok, i see that you tagged your question with "fluid" and "typoscript", but in this case, if the form is in frontend, and that it allows the user to create a database record, I think you should go on a stronger extension, in extbase/fluid.

Comment: I am on extbase/fluid, but even with this stronger extension, there doesn't seem to be a clearcut way to make this happen. The thing is, that the user could be in BE and therefore TypoScript might be relevant, or the user could be in FE, where extbase/fluid would be relevant. I'm flexible :-)

Either way, would it be possible to construct this within TYPO3, or should I just go to JavaScript/jQuery straight away?